# Google Maps Reverse Geocoding only returning "APPROXIMATE" location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am using the reverse geocoding API (client side) to turn lat, long coordinates into street addresses.  These lat longs are taken directly from a draggable marker on the map, so they have many decimal places of information.

If I put it in San Francisco, for example, I drag the marker and send the { lat, lng } pair to the API.  I get back something very general like `"San Francisco, CA"` or at best `"South of Market, San Francisco, CA, USA"`.

I know google has street information in this area because I can use the forward geocoding API perfectly.

Is there any parameter I might be missing that would cause this?  Here is my code:

```
maps.reverseGeocode = function(pos, callback) {
    maps.geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: pos,
        bounds: maps.map.getBounds()
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log("Reverse Geocode:", results);
            callback(results[0]);
        } else {
            console.log('Could not geocode: ' + status);
            callback(undefined);
        }
    });
};
```

Where pos is taken directly from the map marker object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out pretty quickly.  It was because I was including the `bounds` parameter in the request.  Removing `bounds` gives me highly accurate results.  I am now only using `bounds` in forward geocoding.